# Importing fonts with Stylus in a Meteor-React-Apollo-Graphql Stack

Tags: css, reactjs, meteor, fonts, stylus

I have a `styles.styl` file in my Meteor root directory which I am able to load perfectly fine. However, when I attempt to import custom fonts, none of it loads up in any browser I load the page in.

```
@font-face
    font-family Futura
    font-style Extra Bold
    src url(imports/ui/assets/fonts/Futura/FuturaExtraBold.otf) format(opentype),
    url(imports/ui/assets/fonts/Futura/FuturaExtraBold.ttf) format(truetype),
    url(imports/ui/assets/fonts/Futura/FuturaExtraBold.eot) format(embedded-opentype),
    url(imports/ui/assets/fonts/Futura/FuturaExtraBold.woff) format(woff),
    url(imports/ui/assets/fonts/Futura/FuturaExtraBold.svg) format(svg)
```

Note that the imports are relative to the `styles.styl` file. I suspect it's a pathing issue which is causing this, but everything I've tried has not been able to fix this.

- Placing my fonts in the `public/` folder
- Using [mys:fonts](https://github.com/jellyjs/meteor-fonts) to remap the path of the fonts. Once I do this, when I type `<ip address>:3000/fonts/Futura/FuturaExtraBold.ttf` in the URL bar, I am able to download the file. However, the resource is still not loaded for use within my site.
- Moving the `Fonts` folder around into the root directory, client, and other subdirectories, all to no avail (while of course updating the path in `styles.styl`.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

UPDATE: I used the mys:fonts package to remap my font filepaths, and then I remapped my filepaths, so now `http://<ipaddress>:3000/fonts/Futura/FuturaExtraBold.ttf` and so on are links I can go to and it downloads the font. But for some reason the .otf, .ttf and .woff threw this error in my console:

`Failed to decode downloaded font: http://<ipaddress>:3000/fonts/Futura/FuturaExtraBold.woff (index):1 OTS parsing error: invalid version tag`

But when I travel to `http://<ipaddress>:3000/fonts/Futura/FuturaExtraBold.woff` my site shows up exactly **as per normal with the Futura font loaded and interpreted**. This is clearly not the intended outcome but I am really not sure how to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after I was playing around, I managed to get it working by placing my fonts in the `public/` folder located in the root directory of my build. I did try this before, and it was not working as intended and as such I'm not sure why it appears to be working now. Perhaps it might've been a lack of enough testing on my part when I did place it in the public folder (loading in an isolated environment without any caching).

Regardless, this now works.

My fonts are located in `public/` in a folder called `fonts/`, and imported into my `styles.styl` file with the filepath `url(fonts/font.woff)`.